# Driving bidirectional LED Christmas lights

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, led-driver, bidirectional

So I bought a set of 500 lights from Temu and noted that they work at 24 V, with half of them lighting up at one direction of current and the other half when the direction is different. There’s only 2 cables involved.

It came with a controller circuit inside the shucko-plug with a button that gives a few different programs, such as all on, blinking, pulsating etc.

Now I want to control the setup with a microcontroller, but the biggest problem I have is how to wire the controller circuit, as I want to control each direction independently from each other. I thought this could be done with PWM, crystal, 555 etc (probably PWM is the easiest) with the ground being enabled for each direction depending on what color is enabled (probably with a diode to secure the direction).

I’m just a bit baffled on how should I go ahead on doing this. My first attempts using high-current 2N2222’s as a Darlington pair resulted in a blown transistor, so at the minimum I wired something wrong, but I suppose my schematic was faulty to begin with.

I suspect I need to use transistors/MOSFETs to handle the high frequency switching, but as my initial attempt failed, I’d like to understand how I should have designed it before I start to create an even more spectacular magic smoke generator.

Comment: Based on your question, you aren't ready to build this from discrete components. Buy an H-Bridge module with logic inputs. This will probably work: https://www.amazon.com/Controller-H-Bridge-Stepper-Control-Mega2560/dp/B07WS89781

Comment: Thanks, you’re probably right. The H-bridge is most likely exactly the thing I am looking for. I need to look at the datasheet more thoroughly. Thanks!